Angular function this.router.navigate not working
I am facing a strange issue.
I have a logout function which is triggered in case 401 comes in response of any API I hit.
The function is as follows:
constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

logout(router1: Router) {
this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
PreAngular.clearAll();
localStorage.clear();
if (window.location.href.indexOf("/public/login") == -1) {
  router1.navigate(["/public/login"]);
}
}

Calling this logout function following way:
  sendRequest(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
    isCacheable: Boolean,
  ) {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error.status === 401 || (error.error != null && error.error.code == "0101")) {
          this.logout(this.router);
          //
          return throwError(error);
        }
      }),
    );

In my app scenario is that I force logout someone from the database, and in case they are loggedout if they try to hit any API they are responded with 401 .. I want that as they get 401 they should be loggedout. Whereas rather than logging out it throws an error in typescript of the page I am trying to route on after forcing logout. For example for a page it throws error on below function which is written in NgOnit.
ngOnInit() {
    this.activeUserListingForm = this.createFormGroup();
    this.isLogin = PreAngular.getUserInfo();
    this.manager = "manager";

    this.loadData();
  }
loadData() {
    this.formInProgress = true;
    this.usersService
      .getActiveUsersListing(
        this.skip / this.pageSize,
        this.pageSize,
        this.buildSearchParameters(),
        this.activeUserListingForm?.controls["searchInput"].value,
        this.dynamicColumns,
        this.sort,
      )
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.gridData = response;
          console.log(this.gridData);
          this.formInProgress = false;
          if (!response) this.toastr.error("Error", "No Record Found");
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log("Here in error" + err);
          this.toastr.error("Something went wrong");
        },
      );
  }

The console prints:

Here in errorTypeError: router1.navigate is not a function

Function loaddata is in xyz.ts which is ts of the page I am opening after forcing logout and above is oauth.ts.
Following lines are run in xyz.ts having loaddata function
  console.log("Here in error" + err);
  this.toastr.error("Something went wrong");

I tried to apply debugger, the code runs all above line of logout and throws error on this.router.navigate line.
Any guidance and way forward would mean a lot please.
Edit:
The error comes in the file of API I am trying to hit. The above loaddata code is of a sample API. So its not like error is thrown all the time in same file. It depends on which API is being called.

please share the code of xyz.ts, also how does the logout function get called we should do with an interceptor, more code is required!

@NarenMurali I have added .. can you please check now

You need to pass the router as a parameter to the function like so
  logout(router: Router) {
    debugger
    this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
    PreAngular.clearAll();
    localStorage.clear();
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("/public/login") == -1) {
      router.navigate(["/public/login"]);
    }
  }

Then you can inject the router, if you are using a functional guard like so
sendRequest(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
    isCacheable: Boolean,
  ) {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(this.catchErrorHandler.bind(this)),
    );

catchErrorHandler(error) {
        if (error.status === 401 || (error.error != null && error.error.code == "0101")) {
          this.logout(this.router);
          //
          return throwError(error);
        }
      }

If your router is undefined. if you are using a functional guard use, this can only be done in the top level of the interceptor function or class
    const router = inject(Router); // works only for functional interceptor

If you are using normal class
constructor(
...
private router: Router,
...
) {}


Thank You for the help @Naren .. But I am still getting the same error. I have edited my question as per the new code. Can you please go through it ?

@WajihHaider In the debugger, hover over this in this.router of logout and see what its pointing to and share back please

length: 1
name : "logout"
arguments: (...)
caller : (...)
[[FunctionLocation]] : main.js:30416
[[Prototype]] : ƒ ()
[[Scopes]] : Scopes[2]
main.js: 30416 is taking me to the same function that I want to run

Adding to this.. when I run line by line .. all above lines above router1.navigate are running fine. just at that moment it throws error.

@WajihHaider updated my answer, try the bind method!

@WajihHaider the error might also be coming from sendRequest try this bind method there also if my suggestion does not work!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
